# Is a discrete set of points in the complex plane open or closed?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Say, the set of natural numbers, or the set of integers, taken as a subset of the complex numbers. I'm sure the answer to this is obvious, but I feel like I'm missing something, as I can't find a straight answer online.

Comment: Yes. The answer is obvious. And instead of looking for the answer online you should instead see if the definition of "open" applies to a discrete set of points.

Comment: Well, my understanding/best guess is that a single point is closed, so the union is also closed. I've just been confused by similar-but-different discussions of non-topological sets.

What about if the sequence is converging, say $ \frac{1}{n} for\,n \in \mathbb N$ (sorry, haven't figured out MathJax yet). To me it looks like that's open at 0, but it's a union of closed sets. So does that mean it'd be neither open or closed?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: The open part may be obvious, but I don't think the closed part is for a beginner.

Comment: @Daniel: That would *really* depend on your definition of open and close.

Comment: Every set is a union of singletons. So every set is the union of closed sets. Not every set is closed (or open, for that matter).

Comment: But he's talking specifically about discrete sets.

Answer (score 9):

A (nonempty) discrete set cannot be open in $\mathbb{C}$, because an open set is one containing an open ball, and the points inside the open ball clearly do not have the discrete topology.

A discrete set may or may not be closed in $\mathbb{C}$.  For an example of one that's not closed, consider
$$S := \left\{\frac{1}{n} \; \middle| \; n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}\right\}$$
This is discrete, because the ball of radius $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ around the point $\frac{1}{n}$ contains only a single point of $S$.  On the other hand, it's not closed, because $0 \in \overline{S}$ but $0 \not \in S$.

Remember, a *finite* union of closed sets is closed, but an infinite union may or may not be.

**Note**: In the comments you talk about this set being "open at 0."  There is no such term.